# variable in python dictionary for http header construction

Tags: python, dictionary, python-requests

New to python but I'm trying to use a variable within a dictionary that is used to construct a http header

This is what I have:

```
import requests

url = "https://sample.com"
auth = "sampleauthtoken"


headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer "<VARIABLE auth HERE>,
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I have tried a few different combinations with no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you just want to concatenating the strings using the `+` operator:

```
import requests

url = "https://sample.com"
auth = "sampleauthtoken"


headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer " + auth,  # -> "Bearer sampleauthtoken"
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```